# For $x$ and $y$ are coprime. Prove that $xy$ and $(x+y)$ are coprime.

Tags: prime-numbers

Given That $x$ and $y$ are coprime integers.

Prove that  $xy$ and $(x+y)$ are coprime.

Comment: How far have you got? What is your approach?

Comment: I didn't even know how to start it

Comment: Suppose that $xy,x+y$ are not coprime. Then a prime $p$ must divide both $xy$ and $x+y$. Now try to establish a contradiction.

Comment: If a prime $p$ divides $xy$, what can you conclude as a first step?

Comment: Not exactly. The great thing about a prime is that if it divides the product of two numbers, then it must divide one of them. So if $p$ divides $xy$, then we can conclude it divides at least one of $x,y$. Yes?

Comment: yes if $p$ divides $xy$ then that means that either $p$ divides $x$ or $p$ divides $y$

Comment: Great! So if $p$ divides say $x$ and also $x+y$, what can we conclude next?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what to conclude. My knowledge of prime numbers is limited.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

If a prime $p$ dvides $xy$, it divides $x$ or $y$ by *Euclid's lemma*. Can it divide both? Hence, can it  divide $x+y\mkern 2mu$?

Comment: $p$ divides $x$ or $y$ means $p$ divides $x + y$

Comment: Why so? Suppose it divides $x$. Do you really think it can divide $x+y$, given the hypotheses?

Answer (score 3):

I found it.

according to Bézout's Lemma [(Bézout's Identity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), suppose that $x$ and $y$ are coprime integers, there exist $u$ and $v$ relative integers such that $xu + yv = 1$ Therefore:

$$1^2 = (xu + yv)^2 = (xu)^2 + 2xyuv + (yv)^2 = (xu)^2 + 2xyuv + (yv)^2 + xyv^2 + xyu^2 - xyv^2 - xyu^2$$

$$= (xu)^2 + xyv^2 + xyu^2 + (yv)^2 - xyv^2 + 2xyuv - xyu^2 = (x+y)(xu^2 + yv^2) - xy(u-v)^2$$

$$= (x+y)(xu^2 + yv^2) + xy(-(u-v)^2) = 1$$

$(xu^2 + yv^2)$ and $(-(u-v)^2)$ are relative integers, therefore by Bézout's Lemma we conclude that $xy$ and $x + y$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1):

We'll prove the contrapositive.

Suppose $xy$ and $x+y$ are not coprime. Then there is a prime $p$ that divides both $xy$ and $x+y$. We'll show that $x$ and $y$ are not coprime by showing that $p$ divides both $x$ and $y$.

Note that since $p$ divides $xy$, it must divide either $x$ or $y$. Since $p$ divides $x+y$ and one of $x$ and $y$, it must divide both $x$ and $y$. So $x$ and $y$ are not coprime.

Answer (score 1):

If p|xy and p|(x+y),then p|x *or* p|y by *Euclid's Lemma*.
*If p|x,then p|y cuz p|x+y and similarly for p|y*
So p|x and p|y.